Find the process that signals a semaphore in windows?
I would like to identify a process that is signaling this semaphore in windows
uint my_handle = CreateSemaphoreA(new IntPtr(0)/*NULL*/, 0, 9, "MY_SEM_LOCK");

There are a lot of processes in my environment and I need some way to figure out which one is doing the signaling. It is very challenging to break up the numerous processes that make up our application.
I know that this if statement will turn true as our application begins to launch.
if (WaitForSingleObject(my_handle, 60000) == 0)

Is there a tool or technique to find the signaling process? Our code base is written in VS 2019 if that matters.

Doing a text search for "MY_SEM_LOCK" doesn't work (potentially the hard way by raw reading all of your compiled executables and libraries)? Another way could be using Process monitor, but I'm not sure if it logs semaphores.
